# Any way to access an Object's constructor parameters by reference in C#?

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor

I'm probably overthinking this and it's a simple concept, but I cant seem to figure out how to access an object's parameter (by reference) from one of that class' functions.
I need this because I have an object (object A) which is instantiated with another object (object B) as a parameter. Object 'A' has a function which must change the value of object 'B', which could be done by copying the contents of object 'B'. The problem thereby arises when multiple of instances of object 'A' are instantiated with the same object 'B' and must use the function which changes 'B's value. The same object 'B's value must be changed for all instances of object 'A'. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

```
public class A 
{ 
  public A(B b)
  { 
    //do stuff 
  } 
  public string FuncOne()
  { 
    //somehow change value of B 
  } 
}
```

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Right, but there exists another problem, functions of class A cant actually see that object's parameters and or access them directly. Am I wrong about this? 

As for some code, think this:
`public class A {
    public A(B b){
        //do stuff
    }
    public string FuncOne(){
        //somehow change value of B
    }
}`

Comment: Just a note: When you use objects (classes etc) they always passing by reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class B
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A 
{ 
  private B _b;
  public A(B b)
  { 
    _b = b;
    //do stuff 
  } 
  public string FuncOne()
  { 
    //somehow change value of B 
    _b.Name = "New Name";
  } 
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing this (this is actually what my code is doing right now), but my question is: does _b = b assign 'b' by reference or value? Is _b a copy of b or is it pointing to the same object?
because consider this:
`public SomeClass{
B b = new b();
A a = new A(b);
A a2 = new A(b);
a.FuncOne();
}`

what will 'a2's name of 'b' be? does that make sense?

Comment: `_b = b;` assigns a reference, now both `b` and `_b` point to the same instance. If you pass the same `b` reference to several `A`s, they will be modifying the same `B` instance.

Comment: ok, then this is perfect. I didn't know this would assign a reference, its exactly what I need. thank you!

Edit: have your Accepted answer kind stranger :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways off hand, you'll have to choose the one that best suits your situation.

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to make a static variable on object A to store object B. This will only work if you truly want **all** instances of A to share B.

```
public class A
{    
    private static B _b;
    public A(b)
    {
        _b = b;
    }
    // other A stuff
}
```

I recommend setting this value somewhere other than the constructor for this method, but that will give you a picture.

---

You could also make B a singleton.

```
public class B
{
    private static B _current = null;
    public static B Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_current == null)
                _current = new B();
            return _current;
        }
    }    
{
```

Then A can access directly by calling `B.Current`

---

A third option would be to use a wrapper object, passed to A, that could be shared.

```
public class BWrapper
{
    public B B { get; set; }
    public BWrapper(b)
    {
        B = b;
    }
}
```

Then you could pass the same `BWrapper` to all instances of A, where you could reassign the value of B with the setter, like:

```
public class A 
{ 
  private BWrapper _b;
  public A(BWrapper b)
  { 
    _b = b;
    // do stuff
  } 
  public string FuncOne()
  { 
    _b.B = newB;
    //somehow change value of B 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SingletonPattern` to achieve this kind of functioanlity. Something like you create a single instance of B and use the same instance all over the life cycle of the application. For easy implementation you can make the instance of B as static. But be careful for the multithread application. You need to make the implementation `ThreadSafe` for that. For more info:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you make type B a property in type A then you can change the property of B to a new value, however this will not change the value of B outside the type A, in order to change the value of type B. If you just used a function you can use the keyword `out` but this will not be the cause for your example. Here is an example of what you can do

```
public class B
{
  public object Value { get; set; }//object can be any type
}

public class A 
{ 
  private B _b;
  public A(B b)
  { 
    _b = b;
    //do stuff 
  } 
  public string FuncOne()
  { 
    //somehow change value of B 
    _b.Value = NewValue;
  } 
}
```

To make this more Generic that B can be any value you can use Generics and change the above code

```
public class B<T>
{
  public <T> Value { get; set; }//object can be any type
}

public abstract class A<T> 
{ 
  private B<T> _b;
  public A(B<T> b)
  { 
    _b = b;
    //do stuff 
  } 
  public abstract string FuncOne();
}
```

This way the value that B can use can be any type considering you will have multiple types of `A` that can do the same *as A but only for the type of T* 
This way you will be able to change B in A no matter what the type is Example

```
public class AString : A<string>
{
    public AString(B<string> b) : base(b)
    {
    }

    public override string FuncOne()
    {
        B.Value = "New Value";
        return B.Value;
    }
}

var thisB = new B<string>()
thisB.Value = "Test"
var thisA = new AString(thisB);
var value = thisA.FuncOne();
var thisValue = thisB.Value;
```

I've propably gone into some complex code but it really is easy and you can learn more about Generics almost anywhere